# Flex - import AbstractMatcherTestCase could not be found

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit

I am trying to use Flex Unit in FlashBuilder 4.5.1 and I am getting the warning " import AbstractMatcherTestCase could not be found". Can anyone let me know what I'm missing? I have 
hamcrest-as3-flex-1.1.3.swc as one of my referenced libraries for the project.

I am trying to import as follows:

import org.hamcrest.AbstractMatcherTestCase;

Thanks

Comment: I would try cleaning the project, and if that doesn't work, I'd empty bin-debug for the project and clean it again.

Comment: That didn't work. Any other suggestions? Maybe the version of the hamcrest library is incompatible with FlashBuilder 4.5.1?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you importing AbstractMatcherTestCase? Are you writing a new Matcher?

The tests and test support classes are not included in the SWC. If you want to extend hamcrest-as3 I recommend forking [hamcrest-as3](https://github.com/drewbourne/hamcrest-as3/) on GitHub, making your modifications and if they are going to be useful to others then send me a Pull Request with your changes.